# Adding Constraints to Nested Eloquent Relationships in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, constraints, relationship, eloquent

I have 3 related tables as follows  Sections --> AgeGroups --> Teams.

I am able to get a list of sections and list all the agegroups and teams within each section.   Currently that lists all Sections and Agegroups regardless of whether any teams exist in an agegroup.

I am looking to add constraints to this query so that I only get a list of the Sections that contain agegroups that have teams within them.  e.g.

- A section with an agegroup that contains teams **would** be listed
- A section without any agegroups **wouldn't** be listed
- An agegroup that doesn't have any teams **wouldn't** be listed

The tables columns are:

```
sections:   id | name
agegroups:  id | name  | section_id
teams:      id | name  | agegroup_id
```

The models are defined as follows:

```
class Section extends Eloquent{
  public function agegroup()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('agegroup');
  }
}

class Agegroup extends Eloquent{
  public function section()
  {
        return $this->belongsTo('section');
  }

  public function team()
  {
        return $this->hasMany('team');
  }
}

class Team extends Eloquent {
  public function agegroup()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('agegroup');
  } 
}
```

(For testing purposes) My PHP code including the Nested Relationship for eager loading, is in the Routed Closure below:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $sections =  Section::with('agegroup.team')->get();

 foreach ($sections  as $section) {
echo "<h2>$section->name </h2><ul>";

foreach ($section->agegroup as $agegroup) {
    echo "<li>$agegroup->name </li><ul>";

    foreach ($agegroup->team as $team) {
    echo "<li> $team->name </li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
 }
 echo "</ul>";
}

});
```

In testing I've been able to add a constraint to simple relationships, but I am at a loss at how to do this for a nested relationship.

I hope I've explained this properly and thanks for your time in reading this and for any assistance provided.

**======   UPDATE   ======**

After the help below I have the following code which seems to be the same as the suggested solution, bar the addition of a return statement in the model to return the function value:

This is ALmost there - the sections are being returned (checked with dd($...)) but  I am getting the Error : **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$teams**

from the line $teams = $this -> agegroups -> teams in the Section Model agegroupsWithTeams() method.

Any ideas ?! (Thanks)

```
// controller/view code
Route::get('/', function()
{
$sections = Section::allWithAgeGroupsWithTeams();

foreach ($sections as $section)
{
    echo $section->name

    foreach ($section->agegroupsWithTeams() as $agegroup)
    {
        echo $agegroup->name;

        foreach ($agegroup->teams as $team)
        {
            echo $team->name;
        }
    }
}
});

// model code 

class Section extends Eloquent
{
public function agegroups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('agegroup');
}

static function allWithAgeGroupsWithTeams()
    {
         $teams = Team::all();
         $agegroups = Agegroup::whereIn('id', $teams->lists('agegroup_id'))->get();
         $sections = Section::whereIn('id', $agegroups->lists('section_id'))->get();             
         return $sections;
    }

    public function agegroupsWithTeams()
    {

        $teams = $this->agegroups;
        return Agegroup::whereIn('id', $teams->lists('agegroup_id'))->get();
    }
}


class Agegroup extends Eloquent
{
public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('section');
}

public function teams()
{
    return $this->hasMany('team');
}
} 

class Team extends Eloquent
{
public function agegroups()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('agegroup');
}
}
```

Comment: hi this is 4.0 currently

Comment: The solution I've provided below should work for both, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going about this all wrong. Most of what you have in place is correct but try something a little cleaner. Inside of Section.php

```
class Section
...
    public function nestedgroups()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Agegroup')->has('teams');
    }
```

Then you can simply get all of the nested data with

```
$sections = Section::has('nestedgroups')->with('agegroups.teams')->get();
```

This should work for 4.1 and 4.0. If you're testing it with the 4.1 and sqlite make sure you escape the query in has() like so:

```
...::has('nestedgroups', '>', DB::raw(0))->...
```

Answer (score 0):

Update agegroup() to agegroups() and team() to teams(), and then try something like this (code not tested):

```
<?php

// model classes

class Section extends Eloquent {

    static function allWithAgeGroupsWithTeams()
    {
        $teams = Team::all();

        $agegroups = Agegroup::whereIn('id', $teams->lists('agegroup_id'))->get();

        $sections = Section::whereIn('id', $agegroups->lists('section_id'))->get();
    }

    public function agegroupsWithTeams()
    {
        $teams = $this->agegroups->teams;

        return Agegroup::whereIn('id', $teams->lists('agegroup_id'))->get();
    }

}


?>


<?php

// controller/view code

$sections = Section::allWithAgeGroupsWithTeams();

foreach ($sections as $section)
{
    echo $section->name;

    foreach ($section->agegroupsWithTeams() as $agegroup)
    {
        echo $agegroup->name;

        foreach ($agegroup->teams as $team)
        {
            echo $team->name;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Collection.html#_lists
http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Comment: Firstly Many Thanks for this, it's got me going in the right direction. 

I added in "return $sections" to the allWithAgeGroupsWithTeams() function as it didn't appear to be returning anything to the calling code. 

However on you solution, I am running into a problem with the agegroupsWithTeams() function as it is returning an error "Undefined variable: teams"

Messing around I can get a list now where the correct sections are listed (with Children) however I still get Agegroups listed that don't have teams.  Pretty sure thats due to the error above (never!)

Comment: apologies I copied the wrong error - the error reported is "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$teams"

Comment: Did you update the Agegroup method "team" to "teams"?  If not, my code may not work exactly like I thought it would.  I have an idea for a solution if you have already updated the method name.

Comment: Hi, Yes I did.  I've pasted the updated code above so you can see if I've made any 'stupid' omissions in the solution I copied over!  Thanks for your efforts here, I'm new to Laravel and I want to do this in a Laravel-like way and not resort back to any raw SQL, old PHP solutions... ;)